# How can I enclose form fields in an element of my choice in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I want to include every form element (along with it's label) enclosed in a div element. i.e. every form element printed along with it's label should appear in a div element.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice description of how to customize form element rendering can be found in [Advanced Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_custom_styling_when_a_form_element_has_an_error) chapter of The More with symfony book.

Regards.